# Unable to open Infopath2007 files in Outlook 2010

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-infopath

Our company recently began upgrading selected users to Outlook 2010, however we all still remain on Infopath 2007.

Everything seems to be working fine for our users going from Infopath 2007 to Outlook 10. Where we are running into the problem is for our users who are on Outlook 10 talking to other users that are also on Outlook 10.

When any user opens an Infopath file from a shared site, completes and submits it, and then choses to reply to it, our Outlook 10 folks can not open the emails.
They pop open for just a second and close down.
It also appears in their email list with a different icon.

Any ideas on how to get our Outlook 2010 users to see all of their infopath emails?